# Is it possible to host my Node.js server on Firebase cloud delivering by CDN?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have seen that Google Firebase offers a static files hosting solution (for the front end) which is served in SSL and by CDN. That means, I can serve customers all around the world with a server located probably close to them and enjoying good speeds.

Now I want to do the same with my Node.js backend code.
That means, instead of hosting my backend code in my own VPS, that will be probably fast only for who lives close to my server, I want to deploy the same server to Firebase's CDN and ofcourse, over HTTPS.

What I have found for now is the Firebase Functions which is probably a Node.js server. However I am not sure if its running uppon a CDN, so it will be fast just as the static files serving, or that its just a server located somewhere in US that has to serve worldwide.

In addition, if there is such a service - where I can host my back end code with SSL, may I have the "standard" express configuration I have now on my VPS?
And what for about clusters/workers? How many workers I can have when using the Firebase solution (if there is one like that).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. *SSL and firebase functions & hosting?*

You get HTTPS by default for hosting and functions. If you need functions to served from your custom domain and not https://us-central1-[projectname].cloudfunctions.net, you will need to configure your firebase.json file to rewrite your routes to your firebase functions. The main thing to flag here is both options you get HTTPS and certs issues directly from google/firebase.

When you bring a custom domain over it can take up to 1-2 hours for firebase to issue the certificate, but all this happens automatically without you having to do anything.

2. *Does firebase functions integrate with a CDN?*

Yes, but you need to set the correct s-maxage header in your response to ensure the firebase CDN will store it. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#set_cache_control) for more info on this.

Cache invalidation is still hard with firebase so I would keep this in mind before you set anything.

3. *How many workers I can have when using the Firebase solution (if there is one like that).*

One benefit of using firebase functions is that you don't need to really give much thought to the resources behind the backend. If you have heavier workloads you can increase your ram/ cpu power in the google console for your selected function. The endpoint will scale up and down depending on how many requests it gets. On the flip side if it doesn't get any requests (usually in non prod environments) it'll go to an idle state. You need to be aware of a cold start problem before you fully commit to using this as a replacement to your current nodejs VPs hosting solution.

I personally use the cache control headers to ensure the functions responses are pushed into the CDN edge, which takes the edge off the cold start issue (for me and my use case).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have few questions about it: 
I actually afraid from cache since the content is stale and not fresh.
I would like to avoid such a thing with functions, since functions are getting newly data from the DB. I would use such a thing for static assets, which is probably good for Firebase Hosting. That means, I need a solution based on CDN, rather than cache - so user from USA will have server in California and user from Australia will have server in Sydney. How could this be reached? Cache is not the solution - but its something that can help in some cases.